# Callback for cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

**My Project:**

I have an `UITableView` in My project. Each and every `UITableViewCell` have one `UITextView` as a subview. When user tap on 'Add' button, I need to add one more `UITableViewCell` with `UITextView` to `UITableView` and I have to set focus into the added `UITextView`.

**What I've Tried:**

Once user tap on add button, I will update the `numberOfRowsInSection` of `UITableView` and subsequently I'll call `[UITableView reloadData]` to invoke `[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath]`. Here, I'll append the `UITextView` as subview of `UITableViewCell`.It Works fine until this point.

**My problem:**

I need to set focus into the `UITextView` Once after the `[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath]` get called. When I called the set focus method for `UITextView` after `[UITableView reloadData]`, It is not working. I want to know, Is there any callback method for `[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath]`?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What happens if you use `[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]` (for just the new row) instead?

Comment: His question isnt about adding a new row @trojanfoe, the OP is asking how to set the uitextview to the firstresponder after having added his new row.

Comment: kiru, are you using custom cells?

Comment: @Pavan And does the behaviour change if he uses the correct method instead of `reloadData`?

Comment: @Pavan: Yes, I'm using custom cells.

Comment: @Kirubachari fantastic. one second ill post my answer

Comment: how are you accessing that textView which is inside cellForRow, after [tableView reloadData]? are you using some private class property?if yes, check that it is not nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

In Add button action

```
//Assuming only 1 section, if you have more section find sections by `numberOfSections` method
NSInteger totalRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:totalRows inSection:0];

[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];

//If you have custom cell
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.textView becomeFirstResponder];

//If you are not using custom cell, then set tag to textView and
//UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:kTextViewTag];
//[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

after you have called your `reloadData` method you can do something like this:
To get a reference to the last row in the last section…

```
// First figure out how many sections there are
NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [self.myTableView numberOfSections] - 1;

// Then grab the number of rows in the last section
NSInteger lastRowIndex = [self.myTableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;

// Now just construct the index path
NSIndexPath *pathToLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];

//Grab a reference of your cell from the last row
MyCustomCell *myCC = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:pathToLastRow];

//Use this cell reference to set focus to your UITextView
[myCC.myTextView setFirstResponder:YES];
```

Comment: What about the inevitable delay between calling `reloadData` and the row actually appearing in the table view?  Constructing an index path to a *yet-to-exist* row is likely to upset the table view...

Comment: The next line will not get executed until the `reloadData` method has finished executing all of its code, including showing the last cell. On another note, the way I would go about doing it is by doing it the proper way, using the `insertingRowAtIndexPath` method to add a new row, grabbing the last cell from then on and then setting the focus for that textview.

Comment: So you are certain that `reloadData` is synchronous?

Comment: @Pavan : @trojanfoe is right. `roladData` is not synchronous. Still, I couldn't sort out the problem

Comment: Hmmm I believe some tableView calls are asynchronous, but repainting the tableView before doing anything else like grabbing the last row will be fine no?

Comment: rather than saying still couldnt sort out the problem , please give us more detail to your code. :) Simply saying doesnt sort out the problem is not enough.

Comment: @Pavan : Thanks for your efforts. May I know what are the details do you want to know about my code?